# Finding the Target of a Link produces NIO Exception but works with ShellFolder under Windows

Tags: java, bufferedreader, nio, symlink, hardlink

I am doing a recursive search for different types of files within a folder tree. Upon finding a `.csv` file during the search, I scan the file with a `BufferedReader` and put the results in to a database for further operations.

The application works perfectly until it comes to soft- or hard links when the `.nio.` package utilities are not following the link to the actual `.csv` file.

The canonical path and the absolute Path are totally equal. Even the file properties in the Explorer show a "link" the searching for attributes in Java delivers a "not Symbolic Link" Result..

Initialization of the main directory with

```
File rootdir = new File ("..").getCanonicalFile();
```

had no effect. Using

```
.toRealPath()
```

had no effect other than finding the symbolic link files as if they where actual files rather than links, but when it comes to the `BufferedReader` I get a NullPointerException.

I am developing on Windows 7 however the target environment is Linux, JBoss 7 AppServer running on CentOS.

The only workaround - which does get the actual path to the `.csv` file that is the target of the link was:

```
String s = arr[index].getCanonicalPath();

ShellFolder folder = ShellFolder.getShellFolder(new File(s));
System.out.println("FOUND A LINK? " + folder.getFolderType()); //LINK

if (folder.isLink()) {
    fileToUse = folder.getLinkLocation(); // yaaay working!!!
}
```

This is not a proper solution, since the target environment is a server up and running under a Linux distribution not Windows. The test did work under the local Windows machine. Same File-System though.

Does anybody have any clue how to solve that issue?

Here's the Windows Explorer view (sorry it's in German). You can see the created softlinks (if I create them as Hard links via

```
ln source.csv target.csv
```

it's the same behaviour.

[image: screen shot of Details tab of File Properties dialog from Windows Explorer]

Comment: So you are doing development and initial testing of a Java application using an unspecified Java VM on a machine with some version of Windows in order to develop the application for some version of Linux? It would be helpful to know a few of the environmental details.

Comment: yah you'r right. Locally I have my IDE under a windows 7 x64 distribution, the server the application is deployed on after developement is a jboss7 AppServer running on CentOS with jdk jdk1.7.0_79

Comment: How can you tell from Explorer that a file is a link? Are you sure you're talking about symbolic links and not Explorer shortcuts? How did you create these links in the first place?

Comment: i added informations and a screenie to the question above

Comment: I see. That's not a symbolic link. That's a shortcut. Shortcuts are, in fact, just ordinary files that contain information about some other file. These files are only understood by Explorer. Other applications don't recognise them as links. If you want to create a real symbolic link, go into Command Prompt and use the MKLINK command.

Comment: Never heard of `mklink` Windows command until today. [Be more efficient and better organized with the MKLink symbolic link tool](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/be-more-efficient-and-better-organized-with-the-mklink-symbolic-link-tool/) and for the Microsoft documentation, [mklink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) as well as the Wikipedia topic [NTFS symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link).

Comment: Good approach, i've tested with ln under Linux and mklink, but that does not solve my programmatic issue with the "ShellFolder-Object" not working on my server ;)